# How to count the numbers downward

Tags: numbers

It's easy to say “ich bin als zweiter Sohn der Familie geboren”, but actually I'm second to last, how would one tell this fact?
Is my assumption right?

> Ich bin der zweite Sohn vom letzten in der Familie?

Comment: I have removed the second part as it is policy to ask only one question at a time and the second part duplicates http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24742/ich-wurde-geboren-vs-ich-bin-geboren.

Comment: Note that your sentence actually reads *I am the second son of the last in the family* while it is unclear who (or what) the last in the family is. I would likely interpret it as being the last one you want to have contact with again.

Comment: Then how to say "from the last" please

Comment: My sentence was "ich bin als der zweite Sohn vom letzten geboren." Somebody might have edited the body i think

Answer (score 6):

In general, *second to last* or *penultimate* would be translated als *vorletzter*.

> Ich bin als vorletzter Sohn der Familie geboren.

However, that sounds slightly off to me, and I would prefer.

> Ich bin der zweitjüngste Sohn der Familie.

*(second youngest)*

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I always struggle with inequalities, signs and such ;)

Comment: "Vorletzter" like it,and answers are great but i actualy want to cound down like that: second to last,third to last,fourth to last etc.

Comment: You can continue the series with "vorvorletzter". Often you can also use "vierter von hinten/oben/unten/..." - but this does not work in this case.

Comment: @user1474062, drittletzter, viertletzter, ...

Answer (score 2):

Siblings are naturally ordered from oldest to youngest, so if there are a lot of them, and if you're the second youngest, why don't just say:

> Ich bin der zweitjüngste Sohn der Familie.

Keep in mind that there still might be younger daugthers, so you might want to be more specific while expressing it more generic:

> Ich bin das zweitjüngste Geschwisterkind.

Comment: "das zweijüngste *Kind*" would probably be less ambiguous, especially as in some dialects a "Geschwisterkind" means "niece" or "nephew" ("child of a sibling").

Comment: @Stephie _zweijüngste_ oder _zweitjüngste_  Is there a _t_ between two?

Comment: @user1474062: That’s a typo. There is no other form than *zweitjüngste*.